# Pressing top back navigation how to show initial results ,when searchResults are in the same main Activity?

Tags: android, searchview

The main activity which represent list of data,(received from server), on top have searchView, the search results received from server, the data is the same as the data in the main activity, 
I want to know it's good idea to represent the search results in new searchActivity, or in the same main activity,
I think using the same activity is the best option, only after pressing top back ,it should represent the initial results. but pressing top back it doesn't show initial results.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how to do it, in same activity or not:

Just create two list of data:

1. List originalList
2. List searchList

And make all your search with **searchList**

originalList always will have all items

Override pressing of top back and in onClick refresh adapter with originalList

Comment: Thanks, good idea, only if we have two activities, we are not going to override() back it's doing on it own.
That is why I was asking it worse to have 2 activities ,where back action will implement on its own. or to have 1 activity where we should implement back .